# List files missing a corresponding file

Tags: linux, bash, grep, ls

I have a directory with about 1500 files. Each of these files have a corresponding .txt file of the same name to go along with it. Some of these files are missing the txt files so I need to re-create or re-download them. I need to find a way to list the files that do not have the corresponding .txt. Example of the tree:

```
    dir/
       file1.ext
       file1.ext.txt
       file2.ext
       file2.ext.txt
```

I would think `bash` and `ls` would be optimal but I am up to using anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in *.ext; do test -e $f.txt || echo $f; done
```

Comment: awesome. I didnt even think of test. Much appreciated.

Comment: Unless there is a need for POSIX compliance use of `test` should be avoided in favour of `[[ -e ... ]]`.